# When using the openbrowser function of the Rod library to open Google Chrome, why is there a dependency on leakless.exe?

Tags: go, web, rod

In Golang, when using the openbrowser function from the Rod library to open Google Chrome, it relies on leakless.exe. However, some antivirus software may mistakenly identify leakless.exe as a Trojan and remove it, preventing it from being added to the trusted list. Without this executable, an error will occur.

Without "leakless.exe," it is not possible to open web pages properly through the Rod automation function openbrowser.